# Strict conversion of std::atomic_bool values

Tags: c++11, type-conversion, stdatomic

I have a code with very simple logical arithmetic that involves values returned from [`std::atomic_bool`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main() {
    uint16_t v1 = 0x1122;
    uint16_t v2 = 0xaaff;
    std::atomic_bool flag1(false);

    uint16_t r1 = v1 | v2;
    std::cout << std::hex << r1 << std::endl;

    uint16_t r2 = static_cast<uint16_t>(flag1.load()) | static_cast<uint16_t>(0xaaff);
    std::cout << std::hex << r2 << std::endl;

    std::cout << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
}
```

Code example is [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dab3f4350d160f39). Compile line: `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -Wall -pedantic -Wconversion -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out`.

Based on the STD API, `load()` should return the underlined type stored in the atomic. So the `flag1.load()` should be returning `bool`. However, the compiler send a warning that it is asked to convert an `int` to `uint16_t`:

```
main.cpp:13:55: warning: conversion from 'int' to 'uint16_t' {aka 'short unsigned int'} may change value [-Wconversion]
     uint16_t r2 = static_cast<uint16_t>(flag1.load()) | static_cast<uint16_t>(0xaaff);
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Where exactly does it do this conversion? Both sides of the `|` are converted to `uint16_t`. Why is it still printing a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Usual arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) (as specified at §5 of ISO standard) define that any operands for most or all arithmetic and binary operators undergo integer promotion before the operation itself.

This means that both `uint16_t` operands are first promoted to `int` to compute the bitwise `|` and then truncated back to `uint16_t` to store in `r2`.

Indeed that's what the warning is about: there's an implicit truncation of an `int` to an `uint16_t`.

These conversions also define that a `bool` will always evaluate to 1 or 0, so the first cast is useless, but since the second operand will be promoted to an `int`, then also the second cast is useless, you could go with

```
uint16_t r2 = flag.load() | 0xaaff;
```

and possibly silence the warning by explicitly casting to a narrower type, which makes you aware of the fact that this is happening:

```
uint16_t r2 = static_cast<uint16_t>(flag.load() | 0xaaff);
```

Comment: *are first promoted to `uint32_t`*: unfortunately no.  If `int` can represent all values of `uint16_t`, narrow unsigned values are converted to *signed* `int` not `unsigned int`.  This can lead to unexpected signed-overflow UB for `a * b` with `uint16_t a,b; a=b=0xFFFF;` on a machine with 32-bit 2's complement `int` (result is `0xfffe0001`).  We can see from the OP's warning that it's `int`, not `unsigned int`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: yes, by using `<cstdint>` types I got confused myself while answering, I edited the answer. It's actually safe to assume that if both values can fit in an `uint16_t` then no unexpected behavior will arise in this situation (as both will fit an `int32_t` and we're dealing with a bitwise operator) but in different situations this could be a problem.

Comment: Now your answer is correct for machines where `int` is `int32_t`.  The standard doesn't guarantee this, but it's probably the case on every machine that has `int32_t` at all and where `int` is wider than 16 bits.  (A C++ implementation on m68k or AVR might have 16-bit `int` = `int16_t`, for example.)  I'm not sure it's a good idea to use stdint.h types in this answer; the OP probably knows how wide `int` is on their machine.

Comment: @PeterCordes: it's better to be safe than sorry although we're dealing with a really corner case here